# jquery select class which doesnt have descendant with a special class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<a class="class1">
   <div>
      <span class="class2" />
   </div>
</a>
```

I want to select all the a tags with class1 which dont have any descendant with class class2. Which jQuery selector should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$('.class1').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('.class2').length == 0
})
```

Check out [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/2f730wn3/) fiddle